# dynamic condition for relationship(sqlalchemy) in Flask-Admin

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I'm using sqlalchemy and have two models, Article and Tag, it's a many-to-many relation.

When I add articles using Flask-Admin, I want just part of tags available (related on user permission) instead of all tags.

any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do this is to use [dynamic relationship loaders](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/collections.html#dynamic-relationship-loaders). Simply use lazy='dynamic' in your relationship definition:

```
posts = relationship(Post, lazy="dynamic")
```

This returns you a query object instead of a collection of objects, so you can then query it directly:

```
posts = jack.posts.filter(Post.headline=='this is a post')
```

You could also achieve what you want with discriminator columns or something, but that is likely overkill.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need `ModelView.get_query`:

```
 class MyView(ModelView):
     def get_query(self,*args,**kwargs):
         return super(MyView,self).get_query(*args,**kwargs).filter_by(current_user.can_view=True)
```